# jQuery cant parse JSON from answer by Yii framework

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii

I am very new in Yii, sorry if my questinon so stupid.

I am trying send post query with next js code.

```
    var post_data = { 'ajax': 'true', 'action': 'get', 'id': id };
    $.post('/index.php?r=admin/staticPages', post_data, function(data) {
        var answer = $.parseJSON(data);
        $("input[name='id']").val(answer.id);
        $("input[name='lang']").val(answer.lang);
        $("input[name='title']").val(answer.title);
        $("input[name='description']").val(answer.description);
        $("input[name='keywords']").val(answer.keywords);
        $("textarea[name='content']").val(answer.content);
    });
```

Next code in admin controller.

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'get')
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $staticPage = StaticPage::model()->find('id = :id', array(':id' => $id));

    echo json_encode($staticPage);
}
```

In php code I can use, for example, $static Page->id and it give to me id of my page. But in js, I can't do it. Why?

I think, I must serialize or flush properties of my object ($staticPage) and only after this give answer for my JS script. But I don't know how do it.

Comment: Did you look at what's returned by the server using your browser's debugging tools?

Comment: Yes. Server return object with too many fields. I could not undestend it :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$staticPage = StaticPage::model()->find('id = :id', array(':id' => $id));

if (!headers_sent()) {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
}

echo CJSON::encode($staticPage->attributes);
```

Comment: you're welcome.
Keep in note that:
1. In this case, the "find" method returns an instance of "StaticPage", or null if not found.
2. If possible, try to use the encode function with an array